# How to cancel google apps subscription through API?

Tags: google-admin-sdk, google-reseller-api

From [Google Apps Reseller API: Manage Subscriptions](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reseller/v1/how-tos/manage_subscriptions#cancel_a_subscription_or_customer)

*To immediately cancel a non Google Apps subscription, use the following DELETE HTTP request with a deletionType of 'transfer_to_direct'*

So, how to cancel google apps subscription ?

Comment: did you already try to make the DELETE HTTP request in the documentation you provided? Did you get an error?

Comment: No, because i need to cancel google apps subscriptions. DELETE HTTP request is for  non Google Apps subscription

Answer (score 0):

I have filed an internal bug to have the documentation updated and will see that this is corrected promptly.  I apologize for the confusion the docs have caused you.

To clarify 'transfer_to_direct' is the best way to immediately cancel a Google Apps subscription and transfer the customer to a direct relationship with Google.  Customers are given a short window of 'free' service.

**TL;DR: 'transfer_to_direct' can be used for Google Apps subscriptions**